# How can I fix error "_helpers.pageUrl is not a function:" in my KeystoneJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I have guide website and I want to add some tours there.

I created two models: Tour.js and TourCategory.js (similar to Post.js and PostCategory.js). Then I had to create two routes: tours.js and tour.js (also similar for posts). When I was adding helpers I caught error: `_helpers.pageUrl is not a function`

How can I fix it?

I have tried to find if anybody has the same problem but found nothing.
I have no idea how to fix it because I did not change anything in my code (helpers/index.js) before adding my new helpers.

My helpers/index.js fragment:

```
_helpers.tourUrl = function (categorySlug, tourSlug, options) {
    return ('/tours/' + categorySlug + tourSlug);
};

_helpers.categoryUrl = function (categorySlug, options) {
    return ('/tours/' + categorySlug);
};

_helpers.paginationNavigation = function (pages, currentPage, totalPages, options) {
    var html = '';

    _.each(pages, function (page, ctr) {

        var pageText = page;
        var isActivePage = ((page === currentPage) ? true : false);
        var liClass = ((isActivePage) ? ' class="active"' : '');

        if (page === '...') {

            page = ((ctr) ? totalPages : 1);
        }

        var pageUrl = _helpers.pageUrl(page);

        html += '<li' + liClass + '>' + linkTemplate({ url: pageUrl, text: pageText }) + '</li>\n';
    });
        return html;
}
```

I expected that page will load without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because of in your helper file you don't make any function with the name `pageUrl` and try to access in another function`_helpers.pageUrl()`.

You need to add a function (if not exist ) with the name `pageUrl` like this

```
const _helpers = {};

_helpers.pageUrl = (input) => {
     try {
         // ... Your business logic
         return true; // It's up to you 
     } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
     }
};

module.exports = _helpers
```

Comment: thanks, but can you give me an example of this function. (Sorry, I'm a beginner in KeystoneJS)

Comment: You need to create a function with the name `pageUrl` in `_helpers` object